# What does it meaning of "that's original" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sarcasm

Context: *Conrad Greene* is talking on the phone about the painting whereabouts.

> Oh, it's you! Where's my painting? I want my painting. In the mail?
>   Well, **that's original**!

Sentence taken from "*Entrapment (1999)*" movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal meaning of the phrase "That's original" would mean "That's unusual" / "That's unexpected".

Here, though, it's being used sarcastically, as this phrase very commonly is.  The sarcasm is because "It's in the mail" is seen as a stereotypical excuse when someone hasn't mailed or shipped something as promised.

So the sarcastic response means basically "That's the excuse I expected you to give me".